# Missing applications and odd behaviour when searching for packages

Tags: software-center

I don't get this: I currently have two Ubuntu virtual machines running, 12.04 and 13.10.

If I open the Software Center and search from the front page (ie. search all programs) for "mythbuntu" I get four irrelevant results.

If I from the front page first choose System and then do the same search, 13.10 finds what I'm looking for, 12.04 finds nothing.

Both installs are fresh, no preferences have been changed.

Why am I not able to figure out how to do a simple search?

On a related note, why do the clearly intended to be clickable "available on the Software Centre" buttons on https://apps.ubuntu.com/ only show an "Open with app..." dialog? And after choosing the Software Center in /usr/share/Applications nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are these four irrelevant results some magazines? If yes, they aren't irrelevant, e.g. have an article about mythbuntu.

You can indeed find the wanted stuff with 13.10 because it's only in the store for 13.10 and may be discontinued for older versions of Ubuntu etc.

So actually you aren't doing anything wrong...

And for the "available on the software center": Install *apturl*, if not yet installed:
`sudo apt-get install apturl`
and select it as handler for the `apt:`-protocol. Binary: `/usr/bin/apturl`

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right, the four results are magazines and not irrelevant as such, they're just not what I'm looking for - and what I know is there... Mythbuntu have their own distribution based on 12.04, so I'm confused as to why it's not available in the Software Center (their website specifically says it is). Can you explain why some applications will only show if the right category is being searched and not show up if all categories are searched?

Comment: Hmm this is really odd... If I enter `mythbuntu` on my 13.04, I get the magazines. If I enter `mythbuntu-`, I get the mythbuntu configuration centre as first entry... maybe a bug

Comment: I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1261503

Comment: Note: If you want a Mythbuntu distribution (not just adapted Ubuntu), you need to install Mythbuntu from the beginning... PS: Please accept as answer if satifying and set the "affects me" flag on the bug report

Comment: You're right, it does show up when searching for "mythbuntu-". I'd prefer the adapted Ubuntu, but when I start the Mythbuntu Control Centre in 13.10 nothing happens, so I thought 12.04 would be the obvious solution. But keeping the 12.04-based Mythbuntu in mind, there's absolutely nothing odd about it being missing from the 12.04 Software Center?